# Entity Framework lambda expression dynamic query

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

I'm new to lambda, I need to create a dynamic query and I don't even know if this possible.

```
 Parent Table > Parent
 Children tables:
 1. Child_1 > FK ParentId
 2. Child_2 > FK ParentId
 3. Child_3 > FK ParentId
```

I'm passing some params(filters) from the page, some filters apply on the parent level and others to children. The end goal is to display the Children regardless of the table(1,2 or 3).

```
I.E. 
- Filter = Type_A
- One record in Child_1 and Child_2
- Display records
```

I could do this using if-else if-else if but that wouldn't be good programming since I would basically duplicate code and that's a lot.

I assumed that I can use UNION but I will really appreciate if someone can guide me on the best approach.